# Batch - change a variable's data

Tags: batch-file

I am doing a python project, with the SikuliX feature. I want to make an Automatic Mail sending system, but I import the TO, CC/BCC, and so on.. trough a BAT file, which sends then its data to a txt, python imports the txt and then it uses to do the job. But my problem is that when I leave  a variable in Batch empty, it Automatically fills it as 'ECHO is off.' How could I prevent this ? Here's the code:

```
@echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
call :colorEcho f0 "-----[]AutoMail System[]-----"
echo.
echo.
call :colorEcho 0f "Fill out the next part:"
echo.
pause
del userdata.txt

echo.
echo.
set /p to="TO: "
echo To: >> userdata.txt
echo %to% >> userdata.txt
set /p ccbcc="CC/BCC:  "
CC/ BCC: >> userdata.txt
%ccbcc% >> userdata.txt
set /p targy="Tárgy:  "
Targy: >> userdata.txt
%targy% >> userdata.txt
set /p szoveg=">->->  "
szoveg: >> userdata.txt
%szoveg% >> userdata.txt
echo.
PAUSE
echo.
echo Starting AutoFill
echo.
PAUSE
start C:\\Users\\gutiw\\Desktop\\Sikuli\\runsikulix.cmd -r C:\\Users\\gutiw\\Desktop\\Sikuli\\AUTOMATION\\AutoMail.sikuli
exit
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: what do you want to do instead? echo nothing?

Comment: I'm Windows batch file scripting there's no such thing as an empty variable, if there is no content then a variable is undefined.

Comment: I want to echo nothing, so it would be just empty but only where it says Echo is off

Comment: @compo So is there a way to make a variable undefined only when there's a specific string in it? (like ECHO is off.)

Comment: `echo.%to% >> userdata.txt` You are missing a lot of echo commands as well.

Comment: You should use `Call` instead of `Start` for your `runsikulix.cmd` file. Also although you may require double back slashes for the parameters you certainly shouldn't need them for the path to that script, `Call "C:\Users\gutiw\Desktop\Sikuli\runsikulix.cmd"` or possibly `"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Sikuli\runsikulix.cmd"`.

Comment: @Squashman You saved me! The porblem was, that I haven't put the . between echo and the variable! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Compo There are other parts of the program too, where I use double quotes , but  here it wasn't necessary, But the `Call` is not a bad idea ;)

Comment: @ÁdámGutási, trying searching StackOverFlow first.  I searched `echo is off` and found a couple dozen questions of people who already asked the same thing.

Comment: Ádám, whilst I used double quotes as best practice, my example and comment referred to double back slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line:

```
>>userdata.txt echo/%to%
```

Now environment variable `to` can be not defined and **ECHO** does nevertheless not output current state of **ECHO** mode because of forward slash `/` in command line.

The output redirection is specified on this command line for safety at beginning to make it possible to output with referencing `to` also the string values `1` to `9` without getting a trailing space written into the file `userdata.txt`.

The command line `echo.%to% >> userdata.txt` has two small disadvantages:

1. Although extremely unlikely, `echo.` can fail and do something completely different as expected, see DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for details.
2. The space between `%to%` and the redirection operator `>>` is also written as trailing space into the output file `userdata.txt`.

Example to demonstrate the difference:

```
del userdata.txt 2>nul
set to=1
>>userdata.txt echo/%to%
```

Execution of a batch file with the three lines above results in really executing by Windows command interpreter:

```
del userdata.txt  2>nul
set to=1
echo/11>>userdata.txt
```

The file `userdata.txt` contains `1`, carriage return and line-feed, i.e. **three** bytes with the hexadecimal values `31 0D 0A`.

A batch file with the three lines

```
del userdata.txt 2>nul
set to=1
echo.%to% >>userdata.txt
```

results in really executing by Windows command interpreter

```
del userdata.txt  2>nul
set to=1
echo.1  1>>userdata.txt
```

and the file `userdata.txt` contains `1`, a space character, carriage return and line-feed, i.e. **four** bytes with the hexadecimal values `31 20 0D 0A`.

In this case it works also to specify the redirection on right side as usual without a space between environment variable reference `%to%` and redirection operator `>>`, i.e. use the command line:

```
echo/%to%>>userdata.txt
```

This works because of `/` after command **ECHO**. `.` could be also used if there would not be issue 1 with `echo.`.

See also [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it's working now.
The problem was that I haven't used the **.** between echo and the variables.

So it looks like this after edited:

```
@echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
call :colorEcho f0 "-----[]AutoMail System[]-----"
echo.
echo.
call :colorEcho 0f "Fill out the next part"
echo.
pause
del userdata.txt

echo.
echo.
set /p to="TO: "
echo To: >> userdata.txt
echo.%to% >> userdata.txt
set /p ccbcc="CC/BCC:  "
echo.CC/ BCC: >> userdata.txt
echo.%ccbcc% >> userdata.txt
set /p targy="Tárgy:  "
echo.Targy: >> userdata.txt
echo.%targy% >> userdata.txt
set /p szoveg=">->->  "
echo.szoveg: >> userdata.txt
echo.%szoveg% >> userdata.txt
echo.
PAUSE
echo.
echo Starting AutoFill
echo.
PAUSE
start C:\\Users\\gutiw\\Desktop\\Sikuli\\runsikulix.cmd -r C:\\Users\\gutiw\\Desktop\\Sikuli\\AUTOMATION\\AutoMail.sikuli
exit
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Comment: ...yet you ignored the `Call` and single back slash advice I gave.

Comment: @Compo don't be afraid I used it on my own code, only not here on stackoverflow ;)