# Batch Error Redirecting to File

Tags: python, batch-file, error-handling

I am redirecting the output of a Python script to a file.
It works fine if there is no error.
But if there is any error , I wish to capture the error in another file which is not happening now.

Below is the script which I have written.

```
@echo off
mode con cp select=65001
set dt=%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%

cd C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\script
python -u softeon_main.py >>C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\log\log_%dt%.txt 2>>C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\log\logerr_%dt%.txt 
echo "after python path"
pause
exit
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: `python test.py > log.log 2> err.log` works for me on ubuntu. Maybe it doesn't work on windows?

Comment: I tried it in windows it works. maybe you should first run the code without output redirection and check whether any error is getting displayed or not.

Comment: @Sraw: Yes, it is not working on windows 10. I have all the proper folder structure.

Comment: @eiram_mahera: No, without redirection it is working fine. Even the output is getting captured. But in case of error, it is not coming

Comment: It seems the issue is lying `log_%dt%.txt`, the date variable is causing the issue. How to create the file with the current date and passing it as variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of dynamic environment variable `DATE` depends on Windows **Region** setting as defined for the currently used user account.

For example with getting `Tue 12/26/2017` written into a command prompt window on running in same window `echo %DATE%` it is possible to use either

```
set "dt=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"
```

or better

```
set "dt=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%"
```

Both command lines use string substitutions to get environment variable `dt` defined with string `2017-12-26`. The difference is that the first command line references the characters in date string from left while the second command line references them from right. Therefore the second command line works also with no abbreviated weekday at beginning.

The help output for command **SET** on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains string substitutions as used here.

A region independent solution to get current local date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` would be:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "dt=%%I"
set "dt=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%"
```

This variant is explained in detail in answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564)

The disadvantage is that **WMIC** takes more than a second to output the local date and time which makes this solution much slower than the solution using dynamic environment variable `DATE`.

I suggest to use:

```
@echo off
rem Define encoding UTF-8 for console.
%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com CON CP SELECT=65001

rem Get current local date in format yyyy-MM-dd.
set "dt=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%"

rem Change the current directory independent on current drive.
cd /D C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\script

rem Execute Python interpreter and redirect standard output messages
rem to file log_%dt%.txt and error messages to logerr_%dt%.txt.
python.exe -u softeon_main.py >>C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\log\log_%dt%.txt 2>>C:\API_DOC\softeon_project\log\logerr_%dt%.txt

echo "After python path"
pause
```

There was a trailing space in *Python* command line which is removed in code above. See the answers on [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564) and
[Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) why a trailing space in a batch file could result in an unexpected output into a file or even unexpected behavior on execution of a batch file.

And `python` was extended with file extension `.exe` to avoid that by chance a file `python.bat` or `python.cmd` is found first by Windows command interpreter as in this case the next line would not be executed anymore because batch files must be called from within a batch file with command **CALL** to return to calling batch file on finishing execution of called batch file.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Answer. Very much self explanatory.