# batch: FINDSTR regular expression not work

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

```
echo a.txt| FINDSTR /R ".+\.txt$"
```

not work and not even:

```
echo a.txt| FINDSTR /R .+\.txt$
```

Why?

Edit:

Now works!

```
echo a.txt| FINDSTR /R ..*\.txt$
```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt and enter`FindStr /?`, then read the usage information!

Comment: Why?  Because you failed to read the help file for the `FINDSTR` command first.

Comment: We can't know that "not works" means, unless you explain what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) There is no `+` in the regex of Findstr. Use `*` instead. `..*` should be the correct replacement for `.+`.

b) There can be invisible character before the end of the line, e.g. caused by `echo` if there's a trailing space before `|`. Add another `.` before the line end to cover that.

```
C:\> echo a.txt | findstr /r ".*\.txt.$"
a.txt
```

It's also possible without the quotation marks.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The invisible character is the space between `a.txt` and `|` which is also output by `echo` and therefore redirected to handle __STDIN__ of command `findstr`. Everything is as expected on using `echo a.txt| findstr /R ".*\.txt$"`. See for example my answer on [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564) for details.

Comment: Changing `+` to `*` changes the behaviour; rather replace `.+` by `..*` to achieve the same result...

Comment: @aschipfl: great suggestion. I added this into the answer