# Filezilla not allowing connections by batch code via FTP connection

Tags: batch-file, ftp, filezilla

I have a bit of code that will send some info to my FileZilla FTP server that is running on a PC of mine. When I enter the password I want and place it in the login spot in my code and run it. It keeps saying it is a Incorrect password and failing even when I KNOW that the password in there is correct. Someone have an answer?

1 I have tried to change the password many times and even simple ones like 123 and it still did not say it was correct |
2 I changed the security on the server many time as well and to nothing in return |
3 I have reinstalled Filezilla many times | 
4 I changed firewall settings |

```
REM Setup the FTP folder
echo reverseCMD > a.dat
echo *********** >> a.dat
echo binary >> a.dat
echo mkdir %username% >> a.dat
echo cd %username% >> a.dat
echo put Info.txt >> a.dat
echo disconnect >> a.dat
echo bye >> a.dat
```

*** Removing IP's and passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact that all lines of your batch file output with `echo` are written with a trailing space into file `a.dat` because of space left to redirection operators `>` and `>>`?

See the answer on [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564) for details about how a command line with `echo` and a redirection operator is processed by `cmd.exe`.

I suggest the following code:

```
@echo off
REM Setup the FTP folder
(
echo reverseCMD
echo ***********
echo binary
echo mkdir %username%
echo cd %username%
echo put Info.txt
echo disconnect
echo bye
) > a.dat
```

And make sure the batch file does not contain trailing spaces/tabs on the lines with `echo`.