# How to extract time from CMD to windows clip board with the desired time formatting?

Tags: windows, time, cmd

I'm fetching the current time from command line using the below command:

```
echo %time% | clip
```

Earlier it used to update the time to the clipboard in `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` 12-hour format, but now for the same command, it is updating the current time in `hh:mm:ss.ms` 24-hour format with milliseconds followed by a period.
Do we have some straight forward command which will update the time to the clipboard in the desired format? Or at least the command to get the time in the original format `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`?

Comment: `Do we have some straight forward command ... to get the time in [a special format]?` No. A short batch script would be necessary (or a Powershell one-liner (recommended)). Or you change your local date-format in the registry (not recommended, as you need to do it on each computer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get current datetime on the Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format) and [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

The format of date and time output on running `echo %DATE% %TIME%` depends on country set in Windows **region** settings for the used account, to be more precise date and time format settings derived from configured country customizable individually for each account.

The answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564) contains a very detailed explained solution on how to get region independent local date and time.

The batch file below uses this method using command **WMIC** and changes the time format from 24 to 12 hour format with `AM` or `PM`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
set "LocalHour=%LocalDateTime:~8,2%"
set "AM_PM=AM"
if %LocalHour% LSS 12 goto CopyTime
set "AM_PM=PM"
if %LocalHour% GTR 12 set /A LocalHour-=12
set "LocalHour=0%LocalHour%"
:CopyTime
echo %LocalHour:~-2%:%LocalDateTime:~10,2%:%LocalDateTime:~12,2% %AM_PM%| %SystemRoot%\System32\clip.exe
endlocal
```

The local date/time is assigned in format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` to the environment variable `LocalDateTime`.

The characters 9 and 10 in this date/time string with character index position 8 and 9 represent the local hour with `00` to `23` assigned to environment variable `LocalHour`.

Next the string `AM` is assigned as default value to environment variable `AM_PM`.

Windows command processor `cmd.exe` uses function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert strings to integers on using `set /A` (arithmetic expression) or an **IF** comparison with the three letter operators like `LSS` and `GTR`. Function `strtol` as used by `cmd.exe` interprets strings with a leading `0` as octal numbers which is often a problem, especially in an arithmetic expression because of `08` and `09` are invalid numbers in [octal numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) and for that reason replaced by number 0 on evaluation of an arithmetic expression. But this common problem does not matter in this case because the condition `if %LocalHour% LSS 12` is correct **true** for local hours `00` to `09` without printing an error message to console and correct **false** for `12` to `23`.

The local current time can be copied to clipboard on being less than 12 as in this case `AM` is correct for the time. Otherwise the time is definitely `PM`.

For the hours greater than 12 it is necessary to subtract 12 to get the time correct from 12:00:00 PM to 11:23:59 PM.

The arithmetic expression with the subtraction results in having assigned to environment variable the local hour with `1` to `11` which means without leading `0` on hour being less than 10. For that reason the environment variable `LocalHour` is redefined with a leading `0` and current value of the hour appended which results in `01`, `02`, ..., `09`, `010`, `011` assigned to environment variable `LocalHour`.

The wrong hour format with the three digits is compensated on `echo` command line by printing always just the last two characters of string assigned to `LocalHour`.

Please note that there is no space between string `AM` or `PM` and redirection operator `|` because a space left to `|` would be also output by command `echo` as trailing space of the line with current local time in 12 hour format. See also [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564)