# batch removing padding white space

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file that will read values from a .ini file line by line, and use these variables to do other steps.

**config.ini**

```
Folder=Z:\task\first task\archive\
FileName=aFileName.xlsx
break
```

Then in my batch file i read the lines like the following and copy it to somewhere else like the following: **job.bat**

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (.\config.ini) do (
    if %%a==Folder set Folder=%%b
    if %%a==Format set Format=%%b
    if %%a==break (
       call :copyFile
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
:copyFile
xcopy %Folder%%Filename% D:\abc\ /f /y
GOTO :EOF
```

so the problem is at **%Folder%%Filename%**
for some reason, there is a space between the folder path and File name so it turns out to be

> Z:\task\first task\archive\ aFileName.xlsx

I have tried to echo the variable after reading from file line by line and do `echo "%Folder%"` and i can see there are white space at the end of the variable. is there anyways to trim **ONLY** the end of the variable? I have tried some suggestions online, but it seems like it would also remove the white space within the variable, as you can see I do have a white space in the folder variable

Also, is there a way to exclude  some of the charaters during string replacement. eg:

```
set filename=name_mm.txt
call set replaceName=%filename:mm=01%
```

this will replace the character mm to 01 in result of name_01.txt
but in another case, i got a filename that also have mm inside eg:

```
set filename=communicate_mm.txt
```

in this case, is there a way to **ONLY** replace the mm add the end? I know i could've replace the string _mm instead of mm, but there are other cases that the file name format like yyyymmdd.

Comment: You're already aware of substring modification, So why not use it?
 `If "%filename:~-2%" == "mm" Set "filename=%filename:~0,-2%newsuffix"`

Comment: Is there a _space_ behind `set Folder=%%b`? when you use the quoted syntax `set "Folder=%%b"` there would not be such problem. Or does in come from the source file?

Comment: *has* it to be `mm`? You could use `set "filename=communicate_@@.txt"` (or any other char - even chars that are invalid for filenames - as you replace them anyway)

Comment: The loop could be written as `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0config.ini") do if /I not "%%~I" == "break" (set "%%I") else call :copyFile`. However, read my answers on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) and [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) and [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

```
:copyFile
if "%folder:~-1%" equ " " set "folder=%folder:~0,-1"&goto copyfile
xcopy %Folder%%Filename% D:\abc\ /f /y
```

would probably cure the spaces-at the-end problem.

You really shouldn't ask two questions in one - at the price charged per question, it's not expensive.

But for the second question, why no replace `_mm` instead of `mm`?

But if you want the last 3 characters, then

```
%varname:~-3%
```

and all *but* the last 3

```
%varname:~0,-3%
```

which is documented in the `set` instruction - try `set /?` from the prompt.