# Remove specific quotes from csv file using bat file

Tags: xml, csv, batch-file, quotes

I have next csv file with data like xml

```
  "<Person>
      <Name> ""Test"" </Name> <Surname>""Test1""</Surname>
   </Person>
   <Person>
     <Name>""TestA""</Name>  <Surname>""""</Surname>
   </Person>"
```

I want to replace """" with "" and replace "" with ".
I found next bat file with code witch works in way that remove all quotes and spaces. But I dont now how to modify code to replace only specific quotes.

```
  @echo off
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

  set FileIn=C:\Users\PC\Documents\test.csv
  set FileOut=C:\Users\PC\Documents\TestNew.csv

    (
      For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%FileIn%") do (
      set Line = %%A
      set Line=!Line:"=!
      Echo.!Line!
    )
    )
  > "%FileOut%"
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?
To get csv like this:

```
  <Person>
   <Name> "Test" </Name> <Surname>"Test1"</Surname>
  </Person>
  <Person>
   <Name>"TestA"</Name> <Surname>""</Surname>
  </Person>
```

Now I have problem of limit character in batch, can someone post me example with powershell please

Comment: Yes, but I convert this file in xml, so this is fine

Comment: Going back to what @Mofi stated, if you have a CSV file with XML data, you probably want to read that data with a CSV reader/parser and write the results as XML to .xml files. Pretending the CSV is just XML with some bad characters that can be removed may lead to problems with the final XML. Maybe if you ask with the PowerShell tag, someone with PS experience can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove quotes. Ok, that's a step in the right direction.
But you have to save double-doublequotes.

You can do this by *first* replacing `""` with another char (chose one that definitely won't be in your data), *then* delete each remaining `"` and *finally* revert that special char (`§` below for demo purposes) back into `""`

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%FileIn%") do (
  set "Line=%%A"
  set "Line=!Line:""=§!"
  set "Line=!Line:"=!"
  set "Line=!Line:§="!"
  Echo.!Line!
)
```

(Note: this will still delete empty lines. There are ways to avoid this, but this wasn't your question, so I left it out)

Comment: I olso want to stop deleting empty lines... Can you help me...

Comment: Can you help me please obout empty lines...

Comment: for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723595/preserve-empty-lines-in-a-text-file-while-using-batch-for-f)

Answer (score 0):

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processing a batch file is not designed for processing CSV or XML files like PowerShell or VBScript. The *Windows Command Processor* is designed for running commands and executables. There is not even a [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) supporting searching for a string in a file and replacing it with a different string. It is therefore the worst choice for this task using a batch file to reformat a CSV file to a partial XML file.

The task can be done nevertheless with a batch file using following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileIn=C:\Users\PC\Documents\test.csv"
if not exist "%FileIn%" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%FileIn%"& exit /B 1
for %%I in ("%FileIn%") do set "FileOut=%%~dpnI.xml"

(for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%FileIn%"') do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=!Line:*:=!"
    if defined Line (
        set "Line=!Line:""=#q-u-o-t-e#!"
        set "Line=!Line:"=!"
        echo(!Line:#q-u-o-t-e#="!
    ) else echo(
    endlocal
))>"%FileOut%"
endlocal
```

This batch file handles correct any "ANSI" (one byte per character) or UTF-8 encoded CSV file including empty lines and lines containing one or more exclamation marks. It does not support UTF-16 encoded CSV files because of **FINDSTR** does not support searching in UTF-16 encoded files.

The pure batch file solution is very slow in comparison to a pure PowerShell or VBScript solution because of setting up for each line a local execution environment with enabled delayed variable expansion and discarding that environment after reformatting the line and appending it to the XML output file. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** and what is done in background on each execution of these two commands.

Read also: [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564) It explains in full details the **FOR** command line and `set "Line=!Line:*:=!"` required to process also empty lines in the CSV file.

[Batch scripts - cannot display the special character ^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76743291/3074564) explains in full details why `delims^=^ eol^=` is used to avoid that any line read from CSV file output by **FINDSTR** with line number and colon at the beginning is ignored or modified by **FOR** before assigning the string to the loop variable `I`. In this case could be used also just `"tokens=*"` (the line with leading normal spaces and horizontal tabs removed) or `"delims="` (no line splitting because of an empty list of delimiters) because of each line to process by **FOR** starts with an ASCII digit.

The reformatting of a line after removal of the line number and the colon added by **FINDSTR** is done by replacing all occurrences of `""` in the current line by the string `#q-u-o-t-e#` which is expected not being present ever in the CSV file. Next all remaining `"` in the current line are removed from the line. Last all occurrences of `#q-u-o-t-e#` are replaced by `"` before the line is appended to the XML output file.

Read also the DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
The command `echo(` is the only possibility to output an empty line or a blank line containing just normal spaces or horizontal tabs which always works as not accessing the file system at all as `echo.` or `echo/` do.

The batch file dynamically defines the output file name derived from the input file name by replacing the file extension of the input file by `.xml`. The input file cannot have for that reason the file extension `.xml` as that would result in input file name being identical to output file name. That would result with this code in truncation of the input file to 0 bytes before `findstr.exe` tries to open the input file which would fail as the file is already opened by `cmd.exe`. There could be an **IF** condition added to append something to output file name left to file extension `.xml` if the input file name has the file extension `.xml` like:

```
for %%I in ("%FileIn%") do if /I not  "%%~xI" == ".xml" (set "FileOut=%%~dpnI.xml") else set "FileOut=%%~dpnI_out.xml"
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`