# Fixing Exclamation Marks for Contents of a File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a program to make a file that echoes the contents of a file into a new one. For example:

If I had a file named foo.txt with the contents of:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World
pause
exit
```

The file would create a separate one that has the contents of:

```
@echo off
color a> foo2.txt
echo @echo off>> foo2.txt
echo echo Hello World>> foo2.txt
echo pause>> foo2.txt
echo exit>> foo2.txt
```

However, I have come across a problem. If I add an exclamation mark to the file:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!
pause
exit
```

It would not include the exclamation mark in the file.

How would I go about fixing this?

My Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:input
set /p "input=Input Filename: "
if not exist "%input%" goto input
cls
set /p "output=Output Filename: "
cls
echo @echo off> "%input%-Echo.bat"
echo color a^> "%output%">> "%input%-Echo.bat"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%input%") do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line:^=^^!"
    set "line=!line:<=^<!"
    set "line=!line:>=^>!"
    set "line=!line:&=^&!"
    set "line=!line:|=^|!"
    set "line=!line:(=^(!"
    set "line=!line:)=^)!"
    set "line=!line:%%=%%%%!"
    echo(echo !line! ^>^> "%output%" >> "%input%-Echo.bat"
)
echo The process has been completed. The file is called "%input%-Echo.bat"
echo.
<nul set /p=Press any key to exit . . . 
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: Change the line ```setlocal enabledelayedexpansion``` to ```setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion```. Then add a new line ```setlocal enabledelayedexpansion``` on the line after ```set "line=%%A"```. Now add a new line ```endlocal``` on the line after ```echo(echo !line! ^>^> "%output%" >> "%input%-Echo.bat"```.

Comment: Nice, that works! However, so that I can become more experienced, could you please explain how it works or provide me a link for the syntax of these commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch file solves the problem with the incorrect processing of lines with an exclamation mark by enabling delayed variable expansion after assignment of the line read from the file to the environment variable `Line`. The improved code handles also correct empty lines and does not remove them.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls

:PromptInputFile
set "InputFile="
set /P "InputFile=Input file name: " || goto PromptInputFile
set "InputFile=%InputFile:"=%"
if not defined InputFile goto PromptInputFile
if not exist "%InputFile%" goto PromptInputFile
if exist "%InputFile%\" goto PromptInputFile
cls

:PromptOutputFile
set "OutputFile="
set /P "OutputFile=Output file name: " || goto PromptOutputFile
set "OutputFile=%OutputFile:"=%"
if not defined OutputFile goto PromptOutputFile
if exist "%OutputFile%\" goto PromptOutputFile
cls

for %%I in ("%InputFile%") do set "BatchFileFull=%%~dpnI-Echo.cmd" & set "BatchFileName=%%~nI-Echo.cmd"

(echo @echo off
echo echo @color a^>"%OutputFile%"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%InputFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=!Line:*:=!"
    if defined Line (
        set "Line=!Line:^=^^!"
        set "Line=!Line:<=^<!"
        set "Line=!Line:>=^>!"
        set "Line=!Line:&=^&!"
        set "Line=!Line:|=^|!"
        set "Line=!Line:(=^(!"
        set "Line=!Line:)=^)!"
        set "Line=!Line:%%=%%%%!"
        echo(echo !Line! ^>^>"!OutputFile!"
    ) else echo echo(^>^>"!OutputFile!"
    endlocal
))>"%BatchFileFull%"
echo The process has been completed. The file is called: "%BatchFileName%"
echo(

set /P "=Press any key to exit . . . "<nul
pause>nul
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- The **issue** chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- [Remove specific quotes from csv file using bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76776853/3074564) and [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564) for an explanation of the **FOR** loop.

Some additional notes:

1. The command `exit` without its option `/B` is nearly never needed at end of a batch file and is just counterproductive if a user runs a batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on a batch file in a file manager like *Windows File Explorer* or *Total Commander*. It is also counterproductive on [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) during its development. The exception is a batch file which is used for an installation process started from a GUI installer executable on which the batch file deletes itself with the last command line.
2. The usage of `>>` results in `cmd.exe` opening the output file on already existing and seeking to end of the file or creating the file on not existing, appending the text and closing the file. It is very inefficient to do that for each line to write into a file. It can even result in output file does not contain all lines because of an anti-virus application opens the output file for scanning for malicious code between `cmd.exe` closes the file and opens it again for appending the next line which the anti-virus application prevents. The batch code above opens the file referenced with `%BatchFileFull%` just once with overwriting a perhaps already existing file with same name, appends all text output by any command **ECHO** used in the command block beginning with `(` and ending with `)` and finally closes the file. It is possible that this fails if there is already such a file with read-only attribute set or the user does not have the necessary permissions to create and write that file or there is a directory with same name as the file to create (very unlikely) or the file to create exists already and is opened by another application which prevents opening it by `cmd.exe`.
3. It is completely unclear what is the purpose of this batch file. It makes absolutely no sense to create a batch file which reads a batch file and creates another batch file which produces by chance (not guaranteed by code design) the original batch file with an additional command line added at top and with the difference of a trailing space at end of each command line in comparison to original batch file.
4. The batch file does not do correct the escaping of the characters with a special meaning for the *Windows Command Processor*. The characters `^<>&|()` are interpreted literally by `cmd.exe` on being inside a double quoted argument string.
   A command line like

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^Error" %SystemRoot%\*.log
   ```

   in the input file becomes

   ```
   echo %%SystemRoot%%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^^Error" %%SystemRoot%%\*.log >>"ListErrors.cmd"
   ```

   in the `*-Echo.cmd` file producing an output file `ListErrors.cmd` with

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^^Error" %SystemRoot%\*.log
   ```

   and the regular expression does not find anymore lines beginning case-insensitive with `Error` in all `.log` files in the Windows directory as the command line in the input file because of `^^` instead of just `^` in the search expression.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! I will use it in the future. As of the use of this file, I cannot say. I already know the basic functions of the commands that you have listed for me. Thank you for all of the helpful sources!