# escaping doublequotes in batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

Creating scheduled task from batch file by assembling xml file and importing it by 'schtasks.exe' than.

When asembling XML file (important part only cutted)

```
set "value1=eventvariable1" 
set "value2=eventvariable2" 
set "command=%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" 
set "parameter=/C""c:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)"""
::
echo ^<Command^>%command%^</Command^> >> file.xml
echo ^<Arguments^>%parameter%^</Arguments^> >> file.xml
```

got

```
" was unexpected at this time.
```

expecting problem with doulequote excaping, trying prefix all doublequotes in parameter with single or triple carret characters, but have no luck.

parameter in schtasks (edited and tested on GUI) work only if qouted in following manner

```
/C""c:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)""
```

Anybody have idea?

Comment: I would advise your resulting parameters/arguments should be ```/D /C ""C:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)""```. Otherwise I'm not sure why you need to include ```%windir%\system32\cmd.exe```. Your command could be ```"C:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd"``` and its arguments ```"net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)"```.

Comment: Experimenting with this whole issue many week so not remember everything, but think there were some issue with command processor, because this scheduled task have to be started under SYSTEM (whoami -> nt authority\system) account which have different environment from regular user.

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain to us more about your scheduled task; why it mut be run with highest privileges; what the xml file is for, and what its content must look like.

Comment: tested now, and reason is different: when cmd.exe /C is not prepended, than console window is displaying each time the scheduled task is started, whych may be disturbing.

Comment: The reason for run under SYSTEM account is the same: Only this account prevent console windows flash on screen  (at least in taskbar, as minimized window) which should not happen. Whole sheduled task should stay fully in background.

Comment: When you invoke the batch file as the command, it is run by `cmd.exe` with the `/C` option. What makes you believe that is not the case? Also, what happened to the rest of the information I requested?

Comment: you answer both your question with same answer: It run unser SYSTEM account and as a parameter of cmd.exe to cmd window now been visible durring runtime. Or am I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

There can be used the following command lines in the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "value1=eventvariable1"
set "value2=eventvariable2"
set "command=%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe"
set "parameter=/D /S /C ""C:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)"""
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
echo ^<Command^>!command!^</Command^>
echo ^<Arguments^>!parameter!^</Arguments^>
) 1>file.xml
endlocal
endlocal
```

The execution of this batch file results in the creation of `file.xml` in the current working directory with following two lines:

```xml
<Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
<Arguments>/D /S /C ""C:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(eventvariable1)" "$(eventvariable2)""</Arguments>
```

A more efficient code producing exactly the same contents in `file.xml` would be:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "value1=eventvariable1"
set "value2=eventvariable2"
(
echo ^<Command^>%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe^</Command^>
echo ^<Arguments^>/D /S /C ^""C:\basepath\FUNCTIONS\script.cmd" "net_up" "$(%value1%)" "$(%value2%)"^"^</Arguments^>
) 1>file.xml
endlocal
```

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, run `cmd /?` and read the output help explaining the criteria how the *Windows Command Processor* interprets the argument(s) (command line to execute) after the option `/C` instructing `cmd.exe` to execute the command line and then close itself as well as the options `/D` and `/S` which must be like all other options left to option `/C` (or option `/K` and the command line to execute.

The *Windows Command Processor* interprets in general all characters within an argument string enclosed in `"` literally with exception of `%` being still interpreted as beginning of a batch file argument, environment variable or loop variable reference or end of an environment variable and of `!` on delayed variable expansion enabled being interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference. It is impossible to escape `"` inside an argument string enclosed in `"`.

The command `set` itself interprets the argument string consisting of `variable=value` on not using option `/P` or option `/A` special as everything after the first equal sign is interpreted as value string to assign to the environment variable of which name is left to first equal sign. It is sometimes not easy to understand which string after [parsing the entire command line in a batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) is finally really passed by `cmd.exe` to its internal command `set`. In the first batch file code defining the environment variable with name `parameter` is passed everything to command `set` with exception of the space after the command name `set` (argument string separator), the first `"` marking the beginning of the argument string, the last `"` marking the end of the argument string and all perhaps additionally existing trailing spaces/tabs interpreted as unneeded argument string separators and ignored by `cmd.exe` for that reason. Please read for more details: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

There is enabled and used delayed variable expansion in the first batch file code to be able to `echo` the lines to write into the XML file without getting the string values assigned to the environment variables `command` and `parameter` interpreted once again by `cmd.exe` after expansion of all environment variable references before executing the `echo` command lines as that would result in a syntax error.

There is defined in both solutions a command block beginning with `(` and ending with matching `)` which is parsed first by `cmd.exe` completely before executing the `echo` commands in the command block. `file.xml` is opened with creating it new even on already existing (and not read-only attribute set) before running the first command inside the command block. The XML file is kept open all the time for writing everything output to handle **STDOUT** into the file while executing the commands in the command block. The XML file is closed once after everything in the command block was executed by `cmd.exe`.

The usage of a command block makes the output of multiple lines into a file much easier and more efficient than redirecting each line into the file for following reasons.

- There must not be specified on each `echo` command line the redirection operator and the file name of the output file.
- The lines are written into the output file without a trailing space as long as there are no trailing spaces/tabs in the batch file. The two `echo` command lines in the code in question are output with a trailing space written to the XML file appended on each line. The redirection operator `>>` is incomplete in the code in question because of the missing handle number. `cmd.exe` completes the redirection operator with inserting one more space and the handle number `1` left to `>>`. There is therefore finally   `1>>` with two spaces on execution of the command line resulting in `echo` outputs also the first space as trailing space which is the space left to `>>` in the batch file. For more details see: [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564)
- The batch file is smaller in file size as the redirection to the file is only once in the batch file and not multiple times on multiple lines which results also in faster reading the bytes from the batch file and faster parsing the `echo` command lines.
- The `echo` command lines in code in question cause for **each** `echo` command line

  1. an opening of the batch file,
  2. seeking to the byte offset position on which `cmd.exe` stopped last time the reading of bytes from the batch file,
  3. reading bytes from the batch file up to next line-feed,
  4. parsing the command line with finding out that no more lines must be read from the batch file,
  5. closing the batch file,
  6. opening the output file `file.xml`,
  7. seeking to end of the output file,
  8. executing the `echo` command line and appending the output of `echo` to the output file,
  9. closing the output file.

  That are a lot of file operations made on two files (batch file and output file) for each `echo` line used to create the contents of `file.xml`. The write operation on a file triggers sooner or later also the anti-virus application which scans the output file for potential malicious code as long as `cmd.exe` has it not currently opened preventing it from opening it by another application.

  The usage of a code block as in the two batch file solutions posted in the answer results in

  1. opening the batch file only once for reading and parsing all command lines between `(` and matching `)` and
  2. opening also the output file `file.xml` only once for writing all output by the commands inside the command block during execution into the output file and
  3. then finally closing it.

The number of file system accesses are therefore reduced a lot by using a command block for writing multiple lines with `echo` into a file.