# Using CMD read text file line by line and copy to another file with some changes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using the following batch script to read a text file line by line, make some changes line based on certain conditions, and output the result to a new file.

```bash
@echo off
set source=mysourcefile.txt

type NUL > new_%source%

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%b IN (".\%source%") DO (
 REM make some changes to the line and output the result to the new file
 set "outline=%%b"
 REM echo %outline% >> new_%source%
 echo %outline%>>new_%source%
)
```

The problem is when I use the compare tool to compare the old and the new file, I see the line endings are different, and the new file has an extra space at the end of each line.

How to fix this problem?

**Update:**
I fixed the echo statement to remove the spaces. However, I noticed that the empty lines are not created in the new file. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You add the spaces yourself: `echo %outline%SPACE>>new_%source%`. (and your created file will be full of just `Echo is OFF` messages)

Comment: Ops, yes, thank you. I will fix the question. There is still one more problem.

Comment: one problem solved (maybe - better use `>>"new%source" echo !outline!`. [see here for the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for the `!`'s).

Comment: See: [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564) and [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564)

Comment: I chose to close your question as a duplicate, of the main problem with your submitted code. I'd advise that you also read the content of the links in the above comment too. You should be aware that `FOR /F` with `UseBackQ` and `("SourceFile")` will omit lines with no content, or just line breaks. Those will not therefore propagate to the `DO` part of the command.

Comment: I proposed an answer which is working. Why closing it?

Comment: What's wrong with closing a question as duplicate? If the question were bad, we would delete it. Repeating the same answer, again and again, would be bad for this site - better consolidate questions and link to an already existing good answer.

Comment: You can still accept your own answer (after the cooldown) - nothing is lost for you. There is no bad consequences (or any consequences at all) for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will fix the problem:

```
@echo off
set source=mysourcefile.txt

type NUL > new_%source%

FOR /f "delims=" %%l IN ('findstr /N "^" ".\%source%"') DO (
 set "line=%%l"
 set "line=!line:*:=!"
 echo(!line!>>new_%source%
)
```

We need to prefix the output with the line number using the "findstr" command, then, remove the line number from the output including the column.

Comment: This code does not work because of delayed variable expansion must be enabled for the two lines `set "line=!line:*:=!"` and `echo(!line!>>new_%source%` (and only for these two lines). It would be further much better to insert left to `FOR` one more opening round bracket, append left to last `)` one more closing round bracket and `>"new_%source%"` and remove `>>new_%source%` from last but one line to open the output file just once for all the lines and closing is also just once instead of opening, seeking to end, appending, closing the output file for each line to write into the output file.

Comment: `type NUL > new_%source%` is also not necessary at all on using `(FOR` … `))>"new_%source%"`.